# Daily data, different dates

Tags: data-transformation, dataset

I have downloaded two different daily data sets, both for the same period. Together I want to use them to construct data for another variable. However, the problem is that the dates do not exactly correspond. What would be the best approach to combine the data *without having to convert it to monthly data*?

**Edit:** I noticed that the question is slightly ambiguous in its current form. What I want as an end result is *two* series (not one) with the same dates (I will later use those to create a third variable). Each time a date is present in one of the two series but not in the other I want for instance an interpolated value.

Comment: the best approach is to mark the missing data, and deal with it appropriately

Comment: @Aksakal Is there an easy way to do that except for by writing code myself to loop through all the data (they are large datasets)? And then what way would be appropriate?

Comment: If you are using MATLAB then there's fints object with merge function. In SAS there MERGE command. In SQL you can do *outer join* by date etc.

Comment: ...and in R you can use `zoo` or `xts` objects with their `merge` method.

Comment: @Aksakal Thank you. I use Matlab and R mostly, so I will look into that.

Comment: @AchimZeileis Thank you! Could you give me an example of how that would work?

Comment: There are various examples in the `zoo` package: e.g., `?merge.zoo` or `vignette("zoo", package = "zoo")` (section "Merging and binding"). As in the solution discussed by @Aksakal for MATLAB this merely does this merging and will create `NA`s. Subsequently, you will need to do some aggregation (see e.g., `aggregate.zoo`) or interpolate the missing values etc. The `zoo` vignette also has examples for this. And `xts` provides some further convenience functionality on top of it.

Comment: As everyone seems to feel free to mention their favourite software, I will mention that `merge` operations are well supported in Stata with a command of that name. If each single series or the joint series contains gaps, that needs to be addressed otherwise. Interpolation and extrapolation are easy but not necessarily a good solution statistically.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In MATLAB the easiest way is to [use financial time series objects](http://www.mathworks.com/help/finance/using-ftstool-for-supported-tasks.html#bqvwe7n-1). You create `fints` for each series, then use [`merge`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/finance/merge.html) function. It has several interesting options, such as to either use 'intersection' or 'union' on dates, and you seem to want the latter. The default "union" option will include the union of all dates from both series. When the data is missing for one series it'll be NaN. You'll have to deal with NaNs afterwards. For instance, if you call `mean` on a series or `cov` on a pair of series, then you'll get NaN as answers. In this case you could use `nanmean` and `nancov`. Similarly, your regression or other models may fail encountering NaNs. Some methods such as state-space models or `ssm` will work with NaNs just fine.

The "intersection" option of MATLAB's `merge` will include only dates present in both series, so there are no missing data, but at the cost of omitting partial observations.

In case it wasn't clear: the merged `fints` object will contain two series inside. Their names can be obtained by calling `ftsinfo` function. There's a host different methods to retrieve data from the object, such as `fts2mat`, which will extract the series into a matrix, where each column is a series and rows are observations etc.

Additionally, there are functions such as `tomonthly`, `toweekly' and`todaily`to downsample to monthly if you choose so. For instance,`tomonthly` would down sample your series to monthly, setting the date at the end of the month. By default it accounts for the business days vs. holidays and weekends, but you can change that.

@Achim also reminded me of the interpolation function called `fillts`. It interpolates missing observations using different methods such us linear. I would be careful with any sort of imputation though to make sure that you are not silently artificially propping up your sample size.

Comment: What exactly does `merge` do? Your description makes it sound like it seeks perfect date matches, which under the assumptions of the question might produce too many NAs.

Comment: @whuber, yes, it does look for perfect matches. However, OP can use other functions such as todaily, toweekly and tomonthly to down sample.

Comment: Given that this site strives to be software-independent, a good answer would describe *what* these algorithms do. Otherwise the only readers to whom your answer will be intelligible will be MatLab users and many of them will still not understand how to choose among the options.

Comment: @whuber, I expanded the description

Comment: The format is for reading and writing dates. Internally they have the date and time stored as a number. This is common to any software. You can specify many different formats such as yyyy or yyyy/mm

Comment: @Aksakal Thanks again, I have been able to load in both series as `fints` objects. However, I think you might have slightly misunderstood my question. The `merge` function seems to merge the two series and create one series out of it. The end result that I want is *two series instead of one* (I use the two series to create a third variable through a fixed relationship). Do you know if this is also possible in a similar manner? Thanks again!

Comment: I also edited the OP to clarify what I mean.

Comment: @rbm, you should start reading MATLAB's docs for these functions, really. The merged time series object contains two series inside. Look at `ftsinfo` function, you can call it to see what's inside the object. There's also `fts2mat` function which extracts the series from the object into a matrix.

Comment: Thanks. I should have read the documentation more closely indeed but I wasn't entirely wrong: when you don't specify names when you create the `fints` objects, Matlab automatically assigns the name `series01`. When you then merge the two objects, the resulting object will have *one* series because it assumed that the two were part of the same series. Anyway, all is fine now. Thank you again for your help :)!